# How to type styles in JSS with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jss

In a React project I'm using JSS for styling components. This works really nice, but now I'm trying to introduce TypeScript into the project. Most of the things work fine, but I am now stuck at typing the `styles` object.

Supposed I define styles like this:

```js
const styles = (theme: XXX): YYY => ({
  Foo: {
    // ...
  }
});

export default styles;
```

This is then imported into the actual component and applied using this line:

```js
export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

Now I wonder about the types for `XXX` and `YYY`. So far I'm using `any` here, but of course this does not provide any meaningful type information. Of course I could create an interface which describes everything in detail, but this quickly becomes cumbersome and annoying and a PITA to maintain.

How do you solve this in a reasonable way?

PS: Oh, and it's *not* an option to *not* provide `YYY` as return value, since our ESLint settings enforce that you have to specify a return value, so we can not rely on type inference here, or something like that. Besides, there *must* be a type…

Comment: Is JSS mandatory?

Comment: You can look into definitions of `withStyles` https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/master/packages/react-jss/src/index.d.ts#L75

Comment: Does it affect your component prop or state types?
Otherwise why would you ever care about style type? In my opinion that is what any-type created for.

Comment: @ViktorZagoruyko consider a case of working in a big project with a lot of lint rules.